# How do I plot a variable against another variable in Mathematica?

Tags: education

I'm working on a system that has molecular interactions, for which I have the defined constants.

```
r=0.5;
a=1;
c=0.01;
d=0.1;
e=0.02;
k=500;
```

and my system of differential equations, which was solved numerically using `NDSolve`

I put the following:

```
sol == NDSolve[{
            x’[t] == r*x[t]*(1-(x[t]/k)) – a*c*x[t]*y[t], 
            y’[t] == a*c*x[t]*y[t] – d*y[t],
            x[0] == y[0] == 30
            }, {x,y}, {t,1000}
       ]
```

and received the following:

```
{{xInterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},< >], yInterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}} < > ] }}
```

Then, I put in

```
Plot[Evaluate[{y[t],x[t]}/.sol],{t,0,1000},PlotRange{0,500}]
```

for which I received a beautiful plot of both `y[t]` and `x[t]` over the course of time `t`.

However, for purposes of stability, I want to plot `y[t]` on the y axis and `x[t]` on the x axis for a range of 0 to 250 on the y axis and about 0 to 1000 on the x axis.

How would I go about doing this?

I thought about

```
Plot[Evaluate[{y[t],x[t]}/.sol],{x,0,1000},PlotRange{0,500}]
```

....but I received no success. Just a blank plot.

Comment: what is `d` .....?

Comment: Woops, d = 0.1;

Answer (score 6):

Use  `ParametricPlot`

```
Clear[x, y, t];
r = 0.5; a = 1; c = 0.01; e = 0.1; k = 500; d = 0.1;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == r x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - a c x[t] y[t], 
   y'[t] == a c x[t] y[t] - d y[t], x[0] == 30, y[0] == 30}, {x, y}, {t,1000}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{y[t], x[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> 40, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, {"x(t)", "my phase plane plot"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to reverse the functions

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
   ImagePadding -> 40, ImageSize -> 300,  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"x(t)", None}, {"y(t)", "my phase plane plot"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To adjust ranges, you can use the `PlotRange` option

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 100}}]
```

As needed.